# Value of the Yes/No Column

Tags: column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, conditional

What is the values of the Yes/No Column in SharePoint?

```
1, 0
Yes, No
"Yes", "No"
True, False
```

Trying to use calculations:

```
=IF([Col1]=Yes, 1, 0)
```

So if it's true, put 1, else 2.

But not matter what, it only shows 0.  I believe I'm not using the correct datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using:

```
=IF([Col1], 1, 0)
```

Or

```
=IF([Col1]=TRUE, 1, 0)
```

Return the calculated field as Number.

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

Comment: can't believe it was that easy.  The first one worked great!  Thank you Ganesh.